# C# .net core 3.1 accessing to Json elements

Tags: c#, json

I have below code that works, and the response is Json data as below:

```json
{
      "code": 0,
      "data": {
        "BCH": {                     # BCH account
          "available": "13.60109",   # Available BCH
          "frozen": "0.00000"        # Frozen BCH
        },
       "BTC": {                      # BTC account
         "available": "32590.16",    # Available BTC
          "frozen": "7000.00"        # Frozen BTC
        },
        "ETH": {                     # ETH account
          "available": "5.06000",    # Available ETH
          "frozen": "0.00000"        # Frozen ETH
        }
      },
      "message": "Ok"
}
```

How can i access to Json elements in this code? adding Json data to array or variable, i read other sample codes in stackoverflow but i coudn't do.

```
private JsonElement Post(string path, Dictionary<string, object> args, string signature = null)
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(args);
            var content = new StringContent(json);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, this.baseUrl + path);
            req.Content = content;
            if (signature != null)
            { 
                req.Headers.Add("authorization", signature);
            }
            var res = this.client.SendAsync(req).Result;
            var result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);
        }
private JsonElement Get(string path, Dictionary<string, object> args = null, string signature = null)
        {
            var url = this.baseUrl + path;
            if (args != null)
            {
                var param = string.Join("&", args.Select(p => $"{p.Key}={p.Value}"));
                url = url + "?" + param;
            }
            string result;
            if (signature != null)
            {
                var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                req.Headers.Add("authorization", signature);
                var res = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
                result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                result = this.client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
            }
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);
        }
```

Comment: Your best bet is to have strongly typed model to do this.  And it is not clear what the problem is... Are you getting an exception?  Are you getting an unexpected result? We need more clarification for this.  Also the Json posted in the question is not properly formatted.

Comment: Paste your JSON into https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, however if I understand you're trying to access values inside the `JsonElement` type you have deserialized the response to?

If so, you can lean on the `GetProperty` and `TryGetProperty` methods, and the `Item[Int32]` (if the object is an array) property of the `JsonElement` struct. For example `myJsonElement.GetProperty("data").GetProperty("BCH").GetProperty("available").ToString()` would return the string "13.60109" from your example JSON.

However this isn't particularly practical as it could quickly get messy if you want to extract more than one or two values. As [Jonathan Alfaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495728/jonathan-alfaro) has suggested your best bet would be to define a strongly typed model and deserialize to that type instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it solved my issue. I can access to Json data.